# Do pre constructed decks refresh standard rotation?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm a starting player, so I'll be getting the [Fate Reforged Clash Pack](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/fate-reforged-clash-pack-2015-01-06) coming next week to hopefully get playing into Standard. I get this clash pack can be made into a BG Dredge deck, which seems nice for starting a deck but I also noticed most of these cards are from Theros, which comes out of rotation soon, also the logo in these cards is different, also different from Khans of Tarkir or Fate Reforged logos.

So my question is if where are this cards found in the standard rotation, and when would they go out. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to determine if a deck is legal in a format, see [How should I determine whether a deck is legal in a particular format?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18534/how-should-i-determine-whether-a-deck-is-legal-in-a-particular-format) For sets, see [How can I tell which sets are currently legal in various formats?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/9363/6692) or [How do I know what cards or sets are legal to play with?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18923/6692) This question has to be a duplicate of one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clash Pack doesn't effect the legality of the cards at all. The shooting star expansion symbol is used for promotional cards, in this case cards with an alternate art from their original printing. So for example even though the Whip of Erebos is printed in this product with a new art and expansion symbol it will still rotate out of Standard when Theros does in about 6  months, along with any other cards from Theros block. The cards from Khans and Fate Reforged would then rotate out next year in the spring.

The biggest thing to remember about what determines the legality of cards in Standard is what set they were printed in. And supplemental products like Clash Packs, Duel Decks, or the Commander decks don't change what is legal at all. However you can use any printing of a card as long as it is legal, so you can use for example [Smite the Monstrous](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Smite%20the%20Monstrous) was printed in Khans of Tarkir and Innistrad, and you can use either copy in your standard deck.

Comment: Note if cards are released on supplemental products (especially Commander) they are legal in eternal formats (Vintage, Legacy, Pauper, etc), but these supplemental products don't account for Modern/Extended/Standard.

Comment: Thanks, guess that leaves me with a deck for a couple of months, hope M16 helps with something about this.

Comment: @Rono: slightly longer, the Theros cards will become illegal when the set after M16 is released, in the fall.

Answer (score 2):

Theros (Theros, Born of the Gods, and Journey into Nyx) is the previous block; the current block is Khans of Tarkir block (Khans of Tarkir, Fate Reforged, and the as-yet-unreleased Dragons of Tarkir).  Both blocks are currently in Standard.  Under the current rules ([which are changing next year](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/mm/metamorphosis)), Standard always contains two blocks, and the older one leaves Standard when the next block is released.  Thus, unless they are reprinted in a newer expansion or Magic 2016, all Theros block cards will leave Standard when the next block starts in late September (or possible early October) of 2015.